Infinite product of generating functions
I once saw this amazing problem from some combinatorics book. (I forgot the book name) It is about using generating function to count the number of solutions.
$a_1+2a_2+4a_3+8a_4+\cdots=n$($n \in \mathbb{N}$), where each $0\leq a_i \leq 7 (a_i \in \mathbb{N})$. How many solutions are there? Represent using $n$.
The generating function of number of solutions of this equation is $(1+x+\cdots+x^7)(1+x^2+\cdots+x^{14})(1+x^4+...+x^{28})\cdots=\frac{1-x^8}{1-x} \frac{1-x^{16}}{1-x^2} \frac{1-x^{32}}{1-x^4} \frac{1-x^{64}}{1-x^8}\cdots$
and it can be reduced into $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^4)}$, which is the generating function of number of solutions of equation $a+2b+4c=n$, where $a,b,c$ is non negative integers. The number of solutions of this equation can be calculated easily.
Although this is a fantastic solution, I think many improvements are needed. What should I do to make the solution precise? I don't feel that infinite product of generating functions is rigorous enough. Is there any precise definition about it? Also, is it okay to eliminate terms in the back side? Are we assuming that absolute value of $x$ is smaller than $1$ so that $1-x^m$ converges to $1$ when $m$ goes to infinity?

The $x$ is just a place holder, exploiting the fact that polynomial arithmetic handles the coefficients the way you want.  You can regard the expressions as formal power series if you like or, if you prefer, imagine that we are working inside the domain $|x|<1$ wherein everything converges absolutely.

Perhaps you would find a bijective proof to be more satisfying.
Fix $n\in \mathbb N$, then let $(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ be an infinite list of number in $\{0,\dots,7\}$ for which $\sum_{i= 1}^\infty a_i 2^{i-1}=n$. The goal is to produce a triple $(a,b,c)$ such that $a+2b+4c=n$, bijectively. To do this, first, expand each $a_i$ into a three bit binary number. That is, let $x_i,y_i,z_i\in \{0,1\}$ such that
$$
a_i=x_i+2y_i+4z_i.
$$
If you then let
$$
a=\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i2^{i-1},\quad b=\sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i2^{i-1},\quad c=\sum_{i=1}^\infty z_i2^{i-1},
$$
then $(a,b,c)$ is a generic tuple of natural numbers for which $a+2b+4c=n$. This is process is easily reversible, so this correspondence is a bijection.

At the end, you express some concerns about the whether these power-series manipulations constitute a rigorous argument. Everything in that proof is in fact rigorous, and there are no issues of convergence. You can treat these as formal power series, which means we think of power series as infinite sequences of coefficients, instead of actual functions in the variable $x$.

Nice construction (+1).  Might be worth looking for the class of counting problems for which this nice construction works.
